# How to get UniqueID from document.getElementById()?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dopostback, unique-id

I want to use __doPostBack javascript function.

```
__doPostBack(obj.UniqueID,'');
```

But I only know ClientID of my object  -

```
ctl00_cpholder_myObjId 
document.getElementById("ctl00_cpholder_myObjId").id //This will get ctl00_cpholder_myObjId,but UniqueID is ctl00$cpholder$myObjId
```

How can I get UniqueID for PostBack?
Can I simply replace '_' with '$'?
Thank u.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have client id and want to get unique id from javascript, you can try

```
var uniqueId = document.getElementById("ctl00_cpholder_myObjId").name;
```

or

```
var uniqueId = document.getElementById("ctl00_cpholder_myObjId").getAttribute("name");
```

name property will return unique id.